# Account and Physical Thermostat

Tags: nest

I signed up for a developer account using the same account that I have my home thermostat on. I'm getting an error in the Home Simulator saying that a mix of physical and virtual devices is dangerous.

Do I have to create a separate account to be my developer account or can I just remove my physical thermostat from the Home Simulator? I don't want to remove my thermostat from my account though since I use that to manage my thermostat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a good idea to create a separate account.

Quote from https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/home-simulator

"This Home Simulator is intended to be used with virtual devices for testing purposes. We strongly suggest that you create a separate account for testing and add virtual devices to it via the Home Simulator."